# Change data type while destructuring

Tags: python, destructuring

Take the following code:

```
nums = ["1", "2", "3"]
one, two, three = nums
print("Sum:", one+two+three)  # >> Sum: 123
```

Is there a way to change the data type of the strings while destructuring? I was hoping something like the following would work, but it unfortunately it doesn't:

```
nums = ["1", "2", "3"]
int(one), int(two), int(three) = nums
print("Sum:", one+two+three)  # Expected output >> Sum: 6
```

I know I could simply change the data type by doing `one = int(nums[0])` etc... but I'm just wondering whether something like this is possible to do within the destructuring assignment expression itself?

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following. `map` function will apply the function passed as first argument to all the values in the list or iterable.

Note: `map` is lazy. The result will be obtained only during iteration. You can find more detail [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

```
nums = map(int, ["1", "2", "3"])

print(sum(nums)) # 6
```

Now all the values in the nums will be int.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) builtin which convert all your elements to an int
by applying the typecasting function `int` to it

From the docs:

> map(function, iterable, ...)
>   Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable, yielding the results.

You can then use the updated iterator to assign your elements

```
In [234]: nums = ["1", "2", "3"]                                                                                                                                                    

In [235]: one, two, three = map(int,nums)                                                                                                                                           

In [236]: print("Sum:", one+two+three)                                                                                                                                              
Sum: 6
```

Note that this is the same as doing the follows, where we iterate through `nums` and typecast each string to an int. `map` is a shorthand for that operation.

```
In [254]: nums = ["1", "2", "3"]                                                                                                                                                    

In [255]: one, two, three = [int(num) for num in nums]                                                                                                                              

In [256]: print("Sum:", one+two+three)                                                                                                                                              
Sum: 6
```